# Edge immediately to the left of a vertex

Tags: geometry, polygon, vertex, monotone

I would like to know how to know the "edge immediately to the left of a vertex", just by using geometry?

Here is an [image](http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/Research/ArtGallery/vertex_types.gif) showing the problem.

For instance, how can I know that edge e5 is directly left to vertex e4.
Or that the edge directly left to vertex v14 is e9.

Comment: How this polyline is described? How much vertices may polyline consist of? Give us more information.

Comment: The polygon show be a simple polygon. I just want to know the edge directly left to a vertex in a simple polygon. From the image, we know 'visually' that the  edge e5 is directly left to the vertex v4. 'Geometrically', how to do that? Should I use ray from vertex v4 or something else? Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming but about math.

Answer (score 0):

You may keep edges in [segment tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree) structure - sorted by Y-coordinate. So it is possible to find edges (fast) that left-ray from vertice will intersect, and choose the closest intersection point.

Comment: This is what I thought (using rays), but is it the only solution 'geometrically'? Thank you